# Document instance in javascript callback?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, callback

I have html code which renders a table on a first load.

The callback which redraws the table on a radio button event gives two errors at runtime.

> TypeError: docInstance.getElementById is not a function
>
> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

The code is partial since I removed custom interfaces.

Html code

```
<div id = "mytableanchor1" class="mytableanchor1"></div>
<div id = "mytableanchor2" class="mytableanchor2"></div>
<table>
<th>Select radio button:</th>
  <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="radio" name="button1" value="1" checked>1&nbsp; 
      <input type="radio" name="button1" value="2">2&nbsp; 
      </td>
  </tr>      
</table>
```

Javascript functions

```
<script>

function GetView(data)
{          
   var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
   return view;
}       

function RenderTable(data, elementId, docInstance) 
{
  var gdatatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  ..
  // initialize gdatatable with custom colors for cells using data
  ..

  // anchor the table at given html element
  var table = new google.visualization.Table (docInstance.getElementById(elementId));

  // draw the table
  table.draw(GetView(gdatatable), {showRowNumber: true/*some settings*/});

}
```

First load javascript code

```
var global_data;
var global_buttonValue = '1';

...
...
global_data = data;

// pass document instance
RenderTable(global_data,'mytableanchor1', document); 
...          
...
```

Javascript callback code that doesn't work

```
function DocumentReady()
{                  
     // pass document instance
     $(document).on('click', "input[name=button1]", RenderTableCallback($(document)));
} 

// using closure scope to pass document instance as param to callback
// read about it here http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/passing-arguments-to-callback-functions/
function RenderTableCallback(docInstance) 
{
    return function() {

        global_buttonValue = $(this).val();        
        ..
        // modify global_data using global_buttonValue  
        ..
        // now render global_data in table
        RenderTable(global_data,'mytableanchor1', docInstance);
  }
}

</script>
```

=======

## FIX

Fix was to use document instead of $(document) in function DocumentReady()

Comment: `$(document)` returns a jQuery object not a DOM object. All of your subsequent code uses the document object as a DOM object. To fix this remove `$()` and just use `document`. (EDIT: I'm referring the version of this in the `RenderTableCallback()` call

Comment: WOWWW - that did it!! thank you Randy - you are my savior!! :)

Comment: You're very welcome. Be cautious about mixing jQuery and DOM code.